# R: ggplot2 multiple regression lines grouped by variable

Tags: r, ggplot2, graph, finance

I have a dataframe (sample below) with 3 columns. My goal is to have the variable `"Return"` on the y-axis and `"BetaRealized"` on the x-axis. Based on that, I would like to have two regression lines grouped by `"SML"` e.g. one regression line for the two "Theoretical" values and one for the 10 "Empirical" values. Preferably I would like to use `ggplot2`.

I've looked through several other questions but I wasn't able to find one that fits my case. As I am very new to R, I would greatly appreciate any help. Feel free to help me improve my question for future users if necessary.

Reproducible data sample:

```
structure(list(SML = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("Empirical", "Theoretical"), class = "factor"), 
    Return = c(0.00136162543341773, 0.00327371856919072, 0.00402550498386094, 
    0.00514512870557883, 0.00491788632261087, 0.00501053666090353, 
    0.00485590289408263, 0.00576880451680399, 0.00579134238930521, 
    0.00704131096883141, 0.00471917614445859, 0), BetaRealized = c(0.42574984058487, 
    0.576898009418581, 0.684024167075167, 0.763551381826944, 
    0.833875797322081, 0.902738972263857, 0.976227211834564, 
    1.06544414896672, 1.19436401770255, 1.50932083346054, 0.893219438045588, 
    0)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -12L))
```

Comment: What exactly did you try? Where did you get stuck? It's better to show some effort rather than just outsourcing your plotting needs. Did you try `geom_smooth()` with a `group=` or `color=` aesthetic?

Comment: Totally agree, I usually show my existing code. In this case however I struggle with the fundamentals. I was able to plot each regression line individually but failed to gain any insight on how to combine these two lines in one graph. But thank you, I'll look into `group=` and post my code afterwards, as I haven't heard of it in this context.

Comment: I'd recommend to use `method=lm` within `geom_smooth()` as you have very few observations for one of your groups, and maybe a `col=` aesthetic to be able to separate your groups (i.e. better visualisation). Something like this: `ggplot(data = dt, aes(BetaRealized, Return, col=SML))+
  geom_point()+
  geom_smooth(method=lm)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following AntoniosK comment, it seems the solution is to use geom_smooth with a color argument in the following manner. First, transforming you sample data into a dataframe:

```
df<-data.frame(structure(list(SML = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("Empirical", "Theoretical"), class = "factor"), 
Return = c(0.00136162543341773, 0.00327371856919072, 0.00402550498386094, 
0.00514512870557883, 0.00491788632261087, 0.00501053666090353, 
0.00485590289408263, 0.00576880451680399, 0.00579134238930521, 
0.00704131096883141, 0.00471917614445859, 0), BetaRealized = c(0.42574984058487, 
0.576898009418581, 0.684024167075167, 0.763551381826944, 
0.833875797322081, 0.902738972263857, 0.976227211834564, 
1.06544414896672, 1.19436401770255, 1.50932083346054, 0.893219438045588, 
0)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -12L)))
```

In the sequence, just call ggplot like this:

```
ggplot(df, aes(BetaRealized, Return, color = SML)) + geom_point()+geom_smooth(method=lm, se=FALSE)
```

the output will be this one: [graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Irvk.png)

Addtionally, you can add the equation using the package ggpubr:

```
ggplot(df, aes(BetaRealized, Return, color = SML)) + geom_point()+stat_smooth(method=lm, se=FALSE)+
stat_regline_equation()
```

Finally, depending on your objectvei, it may be interesting to use facet_wrap to distinguish the categories:

```
ggplot(df, aes(BetaRealized, Return, color = SML)) + geom_point()+ 
    stat_smooth(method=lm, se=FALSE)+ facet_wrap(~SML)+
    stat_regline_equation()
```

The image will look like this: [graph2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fwllh.png)